# Unable to use Filter_Path with NEST - ElasticSearch 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

On using Filter_Path to reduce the metadata returned from Elasticsearch, I get the following error:

```
: 'Method not found: 'Elasticsearch.Net.Search RequestParameters Elasticsearch.Net.Search RequestParameters.Filter Path(System.String)'.'

            var respones = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
        .FilterPath("hits.hits._source")
        .Index(Indices.Index(indices))
        .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(mustQueries.ToArray()).Must(shouldQueries.ToArray()))).Source(o => source)
        .Size(10000) 
        .AllTypes());
```

Any ideas how to use it?

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/russcam/a427dadb7f5429768450fc8d2118103f. What version of NEST and Elasticsearch.Net are you referencing? Are they both on the same version (or at  least, same major version)?

Comment: Ye the issue was related to the fact that I had the version 5.3 for the Elasticsearch.Net & NEST. Once I upgraded both to 5.4 it started working.